# How to get all entries using graphql.contentful

Tags: graphql, limit, contentful

I need to query items from contentful using graphql.contentful API. Currently I have just two items in my database, but in future I'm going to have unlimited number of them. I've already met the return value "TOO_COMPLEX_QUERY". 
I can avoid this by setting limit to 1, but in that case I'll never get the second record, just the 1st one. 
Basically I can just query the id's of all items and then query the rest information for each entry in a loop, but I fear, that in future the "TOO_COMPLEX_QUERY"-error would still appear even if only entry ids were asked. That's because the number of entries might be huge.

Answer (score 1):

Contentful GraphQL API has `Query Complexity Limits`. You can currently request up to 11,000 entities in one request.

When a client gets query complexity limited, the API responds with a `TOO_COMPLEX_QUERY` error.

I'm assuming you are fetching nested data as well in a single query. You can look at the response header `X-Contentful-Graphql-Query-Cost` in your client to see how complex your current query is and optimise it accordingly.

Read more about this in their [official docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/introduction/query-complexity-limits)

Comment: Thanks praveenweb! But if I need to fetch just ids for more than 11 000 entries?